# on one of the client computers, the program cannot execute SOAP request

Tags: java, windows, web-services, soap, windows-administration

I wrote a small program on JAVA that requests and sending data to the server via Soap requests. It works fine, but on one of the client computers (windows) program can not execute a SOAP request.

In order to determine that the error is not in my program I downloaded another program in soapUI proved that this computer, it also can not fulfill the request. At the same time the Internet on a computer running, and such a program such as Skype or teamviewer - are working.

What I tried but did not help:

- Turn off the source Firewall
- Disable antivirus
- Check proxy settings (they are by default)

What can block the soap requests?

Comment: What the error you are getting ?

Comment: Are you sure, your server is available from client host machine? And there are no routers or something else, what can block http-ports from host to server. Anyway. it's nice to see error log.

Comment: Thanks for answers! http://prntscr.com/94tky0   there is the error from my app. but now i cant take an error from soapUI programm